# Relación entre DOS tablas ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buen día quisiera saber como relaciono las tablas es decir 'Alumnos' y 'Materias' tendria que tener otro modelo para decir que alumno cursa que materia.

Este es el modelo de la clase Alumnos

```
public class Alumnos
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Grado { get; set; }
      
        }

    public class AlumnosDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Alumnos> Alumno { get; set; }
    }
}
```

y este es el modelo de la clase materias

```
namespace Proyecto_Alumnos_MVC.Models
{
    public class Materias
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //el boolean del estado no estoy seguro como lo tome para dar las altas
        public Boolean Estado { get; set; }

    }

    public class MateriasDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Materias> Materia { get; set; }
    }
```

}

mi pregunta es, se debe relacionar en el modelo las clases o en el controlador?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una `virtual` que te indica que esta relacionada a otra tabla.

Te daré un ejemplo de como lo tengo yo.

```
[ForeignKey("ServicioNivelId")]
public virtual ServicioNivel ServicioNivel { get; set; }
```

El servicioNivel lo obtengo de otra clase y tiene un atributo llamado `[ForeignKey]` que indica que esta propiedad esta relacionada con la propiedad que tengo en la tabla donde quiero relacionarla.

Que es esta:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Nivel De Servicio")]
public int ServicioNivelId { get; set; }
```

Y ya obtengo todos los datos que quiero de la otra tabla.